# FTP Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, ftp

I'm working on a project that needs to use multiple types of FTP connections (SFTP, FTPS, and regular old FTP currently). I'm using JSch for SFTP and Commons Net for FTPS and FTP.

The problem I'm running into deciding how to implement this in a way that will prevent other people from having to know about the libraries and also make updating and maintenance easy. Currently I have an FTP interface and classes that implement that for each type of connection. I can't shake the feeling that there must be a better way since this seems to just add a step between the production code and the library.

Are there any design patterns that might suit this implementation better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go is indeed having a common interface for all of them, as well as adapters that implement it for each of the libraries.

Having a common interface you may be able to set the dependency from outside (read about dependency injection), and/or implement a factory that for some generic specification returns the right implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this piece on Dependency Injection?
http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: So using Dependency Injection I would create another class that I can pass a parameter to, say a string, and it will then pass back the instantiation of the specific class that implements my ftp interface?

Answer (score 1):

[Bridge Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) is what you're after.

Since it's java, pay attention to this very flexible and scalable mechanism: [META-INF/services](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider)